# Is it possible to change position of aria attributes in Vee Validate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

As far as I know, aria-required and aria-invalid attributes are positioned on the input tag where you embed the v-validate attribute. Eg.

```
<input class="a" type="text" v-validate="'required'">
```

will manifest itself as:

```
<input class="a" type="text" aria-required="true" aria-invalid>
```

in the DOM.

If I had a div around my input, is it possible for the aria attributes to manifest in the div? So that it will look like:

```
<div class="b" aria-required="'true'" aria-invalid>
  <input class="a" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute)

The aria-required attribute is used to indicate that user input is required on an element before a form can be submitted. This attribute can be used with any typical HTML form element. And `<div>` tag is not a form element so it can not be used with aria attribute.

Comment: That's weird, I believe it can be used with aria attribute because I'm looking at one right now. I'm tasked with converting a current website to use vue.js for the front-end and one of the some of the CSS are reliant on the value of the aria-attributes in the <div> tag.